Where is wrong when I use \tkzDefPoint(\r*cos(30),\r*sin(30)){A} in this code?
I want to make the point A on the semicirlce, but the result incorrect
\tkzDefPoint(\r*cos(30),\r*sin(30)){A} 

This is my code
\documentclass[border= 2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{2}
        \tkzDefPoint(-\r,0){B}
        \tkzDefPoint(\r,0){C}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
        \tkzDrawSemiCircle[blue](O,C)
        \tkzDefPoint(\r*cos(30),\r*sin(30)){A} \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
        \tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto B--C](A)
        \tkzGetPoint{H}
        \tkzDrawCircle(A,H)
        \tkzDefTangent[from = B](A,H)
        \tkzGetPoints{M'}{M}
        \tkzDefTangent[from = C](A,H)
        \tkzGetPoints{N}{N'}
        \foreach \p/\g in {A/-90,C/0,B/230,M/200,N/0,H/90,O/90}
        \path (\p)+(\g:3mm) node{$\p$};
        \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C)   -- cycle  (M) -- (N) (A) -- (H) (O) -- (A);
        \tkzDrawLine[add = 0 and 1](C,N)
        \tkzDrawLine[add = 0 and 1](B,M)
        \tkzMarkRightAngles(B,H,A A,M,B A,N,C)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document} 


How can I get the correct result?

Why not polar coordinate, try \tkzDefPoint(30:\r){A}

or \tkzDefPoint(\r*cos(pi/6),\r*sin(pi/6)){A} section 7.1.2. Calculations with xfp in the doc

You have to use the radians!
I've changed the end of the code to use only tkz-euclide and placed the macros for drawing at the end.
\documentclass[border= 2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{2}
        \tkzDefPoint(-\r,0){B}
        \tkzDefPoint(\r,0){C}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
        \tkzDefPoint(\r*cos(pi/6),\r*sin(pi/6)){A}
        \tkzDefPointBy[projection=onto B--C](A)
        \tkzGetPoint{H} 
        \tkzDefTangent[from = B](A,H)
        \tkzGetPoints{M'}{M}
        \tkzDefTangent[from = C](A,H)
        \tkzGetPoints{N}{N'}
        \tkzDrawSemiCircle[blue](O,C)
        \tkzDrawCircle(A,H)
        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C) 
        \tkzDrawSegments(A,H O,A) 
        \tkzDrawSegment[add = 0 and .5](B,M')
        \tkzDrawSegment[add = 0 and 1](C,N')
        \tkzMarkRightAngles[size=.1](B,H,A A,M,B)
        \tkzLabelPoints[below](B,C,H,O)
        \tkzLabelPoints[above](A,M')
        \tkzDrawPoints(N',M')
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document} 



For the fun with tkz-elements Compilation in lualatex
    % !TeX TS-program = lualatex
    \documentclass[border= 2mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    \usepackage{tkz-elements}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{tkzelements}
        r   = 2
        a   = math.pi/6
        z.O = point: new (0,0)
        z.B = point: new (-r,0)
        z.C = point: new (r,0)
        z.A = point : polar(r,a)
        -- 
        L.BC= line : new ( z.B , z.C )
        z.H = L.BC : projection (z.A)
        --
        C.AH = circle : new (z.A,z.H)
        L.T1,_ = C.AH : tangent_from (z.B)
        z.M    = L.T1.pb
        --
        _,L.T2 = C.AH : tangent_from (z.C)
        z.N    = L.T2.pb
    \end{tkzelements}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzGetNodes
        \tkzDrawSemiCircle[blue](O,C)
        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
        \tkzDrawCircle(A,H)
        %\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,H,O,M,N)
        \tkzLabelPoints[font=\tiny](B,C,H,O,N)
        \tkzLabelPoints[font=\tiny,above](A,M)
        \tkzDrawLine[add = 0 and 1](B,M)
        \tkzDrawLine[add = 0 and 1](C,N)
        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C) 
        \tkzDrawSegments(A,H O,A A,M A,N)
        \tkzMarkRightAngles[size=.1](B,H,A A,M,B A,N,C)
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document} 



Good example of the use of tkz-elements.I hope you like to use it

@Alain Matthes, I'm fan
